# React - opening modal from presentational component from another component won't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components and want to open up a modal, but only when another event occurs (first event is click on a text, change that text and only then should be the modal displayed). Im new to react and since I have those 2 events Im confused on how to pass in props to another component. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

App component

```
  class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
              super(props)
              this.state = {
                  display: false,
                  modal: false
              }

              this.toggle = function() {
                  this.setState({
                      display: !this.state.display
                  });
              }.bind(this);

              this.showModal = function() {
                  this.setState({
                      modal: true
                  });
              }.bind(this);

              this.hideModal = function() {
                  this.setState({
                      modal: false
                  });
              }.bind(this);
          }
          componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
              if (!prevState.display && this.state.display) {
                  if (!this.state.modal) {
                      setTimeout(this.showModal, 1000);
                  }
              }

          }

          render() {

              const msg = this.state.display ? <p>hey</p> : <p>bye</p>,
                  modal = this.state.modal ? (
                      <AModal onClick={this.toggle} />
                  ) : null;
              return (
                  <div>
                <a onClick={this.toggle}><p>{msg}</p></a>
                {modal}
              </div>
              );
          }
      }
```

Modal Component

```
    import Modal from 'react-modal';

    class AModal extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const customStyles = {
                content: {
                    top: '50%',
                    left: '40%',
                    right: 'auto',
                    bottom: 'auto',
                    marginRight: '-50%',
                    background: '#91c11e',
                    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
                }
            };

            return (
                <div>
                  <Modal
                      isOpen={this.state.modal}
                      onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                      onRequestClose={this.hideModal}
                      style={customStyles}
                      contentLabel="Example Modal">
                      <h2>hey</h2>

                  </Modal>
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal `isOpen` is being controlled by the state of `class AModal`, not from `class App`.

```
<Modal
    isOpen={this.state.modal}
    ...
</Modal>
```

I believe you will need to pass the prop that controls the hidden/visible state of the modal down to that component.

So something like this (replacing the state with either `this.state.modal` or `this.state.display`:

```
<AModal
    onClick={this.toggle}
    isOpen={this.state.whatever_state_property_controls_modal_visibility} />
```

And then in your modal component:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} ...
```

As an aside, I would update the methods you create in the constructor of `App` to be class methods:

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
              display: false,
              modal: false
          }

          this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
          // rest of the methods
      }


      toggle() {
          this.setState({
              display: !this.state.display
          });
      }

      ...
  }
```